# Reactivity of different isomers of N2F2

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reactivity, isomers

$\ce{ N2F2}$ exists in two forms cis and trans. Today my chemistry teacher tells me that among the two only cis form takes part in reactions and that it is more reactive. But I have read elsewhere that trans is less stable. As far as I understand less stable compounds are usually more reactive. So why this discrepancy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Dinitrogen Difluoride Chemistry](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic100471s) *Inorg. Chem.*, 2010, 49 (15), pp 6823–6833:

> This increased reactivity of the *cis*-isomer can be readily
>   explained. In both $\ce{N2F2}$ isomers, each nitrogen atom
>   possesses a sterically active free valence electron pair.
>   The transformation of $\ce{N2F2}$ to $\ce{N2F+}$ requires the conversion
>   of the $\ce{N=N}$ double bond into a $\ce{N#N}$ triple bond
>   by an overlap of electrons from these two free valence electron pairs. Obviously, this overlap is greatly facilitated
>   in *cis*-$\ce{N2F2}$, where these free pairs are on the same
>   side of the molecule.